# Grey shadow left behind when closing dialog

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, modal-dialog

I use angular ModalService for dialog in my app. When I want to close dialog, black shadow left behind. My controllers :

```
angular.module("app")
.controller('TreeController', ['$scope', 'asyncService', 'ModalService', 'dataService',
    function ($scope, asyncService, ModalService, dataService) {

        $scope.showJobModal = function (id) {
            dataService.setCurrentJobId(id);
            ModalService.showModal({
                    templateUrl: 'modal.html',
                    controller: "ModalController",
                    preClose: function (modal) {
                        modal.element.modal('hide');
                    }
                }
            ).then(function(modal) {
                modal.element.modal();
                modal.close.then(function() {
                    console.log("closed job modal")
                });
            });
        }

    }]);

angular.module('app').controller('ModalController', ['$scope', 'asyncService', 'dataService', 'ModalService', 'close',
    function ($scope, asyncService, dataService, ModalService, close) {
        asyncService.getJob(dataService.getCurrentJobId()).then(function (response) {
            $scope.job = response;
        });

        $scope.close = function() {
            close(500);
        };

    }]);
```

When I click outside dialog, it closes just fine. But when I want close it on $scope.close, black shadow left behind. I tried this : [close modal release](https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service/releases/tag/v0.12.0), but everything is the same. Any suggestion?

Comment: Go for $uibModalStack.dismissAll();. It might help you

OR

you can use $("selector).modal('hide');

Comment: where should I put that? In my close function?

Comment: yes. $scope.close = function() {
            $uibModalStack.dismissAll();
        };

Inject $uibModalStack to your controller.

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.closeModal = function () {
    $uibModalStack.dismissAll();
}
```

Inject `$uibModalStack` to your controller

Comment: It helped when I have 1 modal. But on close one modal, I need to open the second. And that does not work.

Comment: you can open 2nd modal after calling $uibModalStack.dismissAll(); as $uibModalStack.dismissAll(); dismissed all modals at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Use $uibModal 
https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/74exww04/

```
Example:
     $scope.dialogOpen = function () { 
        var modal = $uibModal.open ({
          backdrop: false,
          templateUrl: './abc.html',
          controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.close = function () {
              modal.dismiss('cancel');
            };
          };
       });
    };
```